# Trying to move the icons next to each other

Tags: css, font-awesome

After figuring out easy ways to implement icons to my blog. I wanted to make it a bit pretty by putting the Thumbs down Icon side by side with Thumbs up icon or vice versa. For example like youtube's like and dislike buttons. Right now it is underneath the thumbs down button. Hope you can understand, If any questions comment it down below.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="{% url 'dislike_post' post.pk %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if liked %}

            
        {% elif disliked %}

            <button style=" display:block; margin:0.5em; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: center; color: blue;",type='submit', name='post_id', value="{{ post.id }}", class="btn btn-light"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down fa-2x"></i></button>
             {{ total_dislikes }} Dislikes
             <br><br>
             {{ total_likes }} Likes
        {% else %}
            <button style="display:block; margin:0.5em; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: center;", type='submit', name='post_id', value="{{ post.id }}", class="btn btn-light"><i class='fas fa-thumbs-down fa-2x'></i></button> 
            {{ total_dislikes }} Dislikes

        {% endif %}

    {% else %}
        <small><a href="{% url 'login' %}" >Login to like and dislike the post</small>
                {{ total_dislikes }} Dislikes
                <br><br>
                {{ total_likes }} Likes
    {% endif %}
        <br>
        
        <br>
    </form>
    <form action="{% url 'like_post' post.pk %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if liked %}

            <button style="color: blue; display:block; margin:0.5em; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: center;" type='submit', name='post_id', value="{{ post.id }}", class="btn btn-light"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-2x"></i></button>
            {{ total_dislikes }} Dislikes
            <br><br>
            {{ total_likes }} Likes
        {% elif disliked %}


        {% else %}
            <button style="display:block; margin:0.5em; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: center;"type='submit', name='post_id', value="{{ post.id }}", class="btn btn-light"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-2x"></i></button>
            {{ total_likes }} Likes

</form>
        {% endif %}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want..

Comment: I want to put the thumbs up icon and thumbs down icon next to each other, side by side. @shotgun02

Comment: It will be helpful if you put some working code in the question so that it will be easier us to suggest solutions.

Comment: @shotgun02 I am not sure what working code. exactly that I ought give you.

Answer (score 0):

You have put an inline style on the `button` tags, displaying them as `block` elements. You can put the `display` property of the buttons to `inline-block`, and remove the `<br>` tags, for them to align side to side.

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button>Thumbs up</button>
<button>Thumbs down</button>
14 likes
```

Alternatively, you could wrap the elements you want to have next to each other in an element with `flexbox`.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.a {
  background: red;
}


.b {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">I am a block-level element</div>
  <div class="b">I am a block-level element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It did not wok.